# What is the recommended way to call a function in another component when a button is clicked in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

I m really sorry if this question is answered a thousand times before, I m really new to React, and don't know how to describe what I want to say in correct words to search for it.

I have a canvas component (A simple HTML canvas and I am using fabric.js on top of it) and a sidebar component (Which contains quite a few buttons such as a button to change line thickness, line color etc). Now what I want is when I click on the button in the sidebar (say, change line color button), it will call a function in canvas component or anywhere else, that sets the color property to be used for canvas drawing.

IMPORTANT: After a bit of googling what I found is that React encourages self-containment, all logic for a component should be inside it. But I am trying to make a whiteboard app. There are different toolbox, menu, sidebar components - all of which affect my canvas. I was writing the code for it in plain HTML, CSS, JavaScript. But I soon realized that my code was getting too difficult to read and modify. This is where I searched for something that lets me break my HTML code into pieces for easy management - such as one HTML code for toolbox, another one for the sidebar etc. And React and similar frameworks appeared. React does the job I originally searched for - breaking my code into components. But I am not getting how to do the following in React:

````
```var lineColor = #000000; const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-id"); const lineColorButton = document.getElementById("line-color-button-id"); lineColorButton.addEventListened("click", () => {lineColor = #ff0000;})```
````

ANOTHER IMPORTANT NOTE: I do not want to use React as it is a bit too overwhelming for me right now. I wanted to stick with simple HTML. I just wanted a solution to break my HTML code into pieces for easy management. PLEASE any type of advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent component can contain the methods you want, and pass the function to the child component.

The following it just typed out by hand, so may contain typos...

```
// In the parent component:
const onEraseToolClicked = (aParam) => {
  console.log(`Erase tool with ${aParam} was clicked`)
}

// optionally memoize the function so it won't cause re-render unless a variable it uses changes
const onEraseToolClickedMemo = useCallback(onEraseToolClicked, [])

return (
  <>
    <Toolbar onEraseToolClicked={onEraseToolClickedMemo} />
  </>
)

//IN THE Toolbar.js File
function Toolbar({ onEraseToolClickedMemo }) {

  return (
    <>
      <button type='button' onClick={onEraseToolClickedMemo}>click me</button>
      <button type='button' onClick={()=>onEraseToolClickedMemo('hello')} >no click me</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

EDIT: You may also look into using [react's context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can put the toolbar state and methods to set/change it's state into the context. Then wrap your command pallet and the canvas with the context. This will make it easier to deal with a lot of state and toolbar items.

Comment: Really thanks a lot for your help. I would look react context. I just wanted to tell you that I find using React really complicated for now. I would want to stick to plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I just want to find a simple tool to manage my large HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have an accepted answer, but if you wanted to stick with vanilla js you could set up a class to manage the canvas. The class could expose whatever functionality you need and your toolbar controls could just invoke those methods.

Here's a very rudimentary proof of concept.

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor (context) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.fillColorIndex = 0;
    this.paint();
  }

  onFillChange () {
    // cycle to the next color
    this.ctx.fillStyle = colors[this.fillColorIndex++ % colors.length];
    
    // redraw
    this.paint();
  }
  
  paint () {
    // fill a rect so we have something to look at
    this.ctx.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
  }
}

// get references to the canvas and button dom elements
const elem = document.querySelector('canvas');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// list of fill styles to cycle through
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'tomato', 'bisque',];

// instantiate the class with the canvas element's 2d context.
const c = new Canvas(elem.getContext('2d'));

// set up the button to invoke a method on the instance
button.addEventListener('click', () => c.onFillChange())
```

```css
/* just basic layout stuff. not relevant to the functionality */
.demo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <button>Next Color</button>
  <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But as I said in comment for the other answer, my main objective is to find a way to divide my large HTML file into manageable pieces.

Comment: You said you're using React but don't want to use React and want to use simple HTML and vanilla js, but now you don't want to do that, so it's not obvious what you actually want.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for to break up your HTML is "templating language".